# GridBagLayout - different row size

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

normally, i'm not that bad with Swing and the different Layouts, but this one is really bugging me out.

What's wrong on the following chart using GridBagLayout? Every thick rectange is an JPanel.
The thin lines are just helper for the right y values.

Thanks in advance!

[image: Mein Problem]

```
package at;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GridMask extends JFrame {

JPanel jPanel1, jPanel2, jPanel3, jPanel4, jPanel5, jPanel6;

public GridMask() {
    unimportantStuff();

    GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
    setLayout(gbl);

    GridBagConstraints gbc;

    gbc = getGbc(0, 0, 3, 1, 0.5);
    gbl.setConstraints(jPanel1, gbc);

    gbc = getGbc(1, 0, 4, 1, 0.75);
    gbl.setConstraints(jPanel2, gbc);

    gbc = getGbc(2, 0, 3, 1, 0.5);
    gbl.setConstraints(jPanel3, gbc);

    gbc = getGbc(0, 3, 3, 1, 0.5);
    gbl.setConstraints(jPanel4, gbc);

    gbc = getGbc(1, 4, 2, 1, 0.25);
    gbl.setConstraints(jPanel5, gbc);

    gbc = getGbc(2, 3, 3, 1, 0.5);
    gbl.setConstraints(jPanel6, gbc);

    add(jPanel1);
    add(jPanel2);
    add(jPanel3);
    add(jPanel4);
    add(jPanel5);
    add(jPanel6);

    setVisible(true);
}

private GridBagConstraints getGbc(int x, int y, int height, int width, double weightY) {
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridx = x;
    gbc.gridy = y;
    gbc.gridheight = height;
    gbc.gridwidth = width;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.weightx = 1.0;
    gbc.weighty = weightY;

    return gbc;
}

private void unimportantStuff() {
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jPanel4 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jPanel5 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jPanel6 = new javax.swing.JPanel();

    jPanel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    jPanel2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    jPanel3.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    jPanel4.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    jPanel5.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    jPanel6.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new GridMask();
}
}
```

The result is a JFrame where the two rows have different heights, but the cells in a row have all the same height.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. The chart looks fine to me. Post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @camickr: Added; MarkW: sorry, just a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but the cells in a row have all the same height.

```
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
```

You are telling the layout to size all the components to fill the space available in each cell.

Comment: Shouldn't the weighty in combination with the fill tell the layout that this column has two rows, one using 3/4 of the panel size and one with 1/4? Am I wrong or should the fill only make the use all the place, vut still respecting the weight?

Comment: @NeedCoffee, The "weighty" constraint is used to indicate what happens on resizing behaviour. Components are allocated their preferred size. Then if you have an extra 40 pixels to use the space is allocated based on the "weighty" percentages. So  components will get .75, .25, or .50. If you use "fill", then all the components will be resized to the maximum space. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for a more detailed explanation on how the constraints work.